# What is the default and maximum block size in Hyperledger Sawtooth Blockchain

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger, hyperledger-sawtooth

I am adding some user data in the blocks of Sawtooth Blockchain. I need to check how much data can be added to a single block.
Is the block size configurable? If yes How can I do it?
I read documentation but not getting any concrete information.

Answer (score 1):

There is no size limit on what can be put in the state store. However, you wouldn't want a big blob be stored on chain. You could however limit maximum batches that can be part of one block.

Block (as in the block created) will reference the list of transactions from the transaction receipts store, and will reference the state root hash from the state store.

Comment: The documentation supports this answer: https://sawtooth.hyperledger.org/faq/transaction-processing/#what-is-the-size-limit-for-a-sawtooth-transaction